# How to move down a division in CSS for wordpress website?

Tags: css, wordpress

Sir/mam
I am a beginner, please help me how to move down a division using additional CSS for a WordPress website,

I want to put down related posts division just below the answer division

I had tried relative positioning but it does not work, maybe I had applied it wrong...

[image]

Comment: You must edit .php files in theme, not .css. You have some file(post.php, page.php i.e.), this blocks order described there.

Comment: Thanks mam for trying to help me out but there is around 50 .php files with around 4000 of code in each. How can I find which one is desired one .php file? Please help me out!!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with `flexbox`.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box :nth-child(1) {
  order: 2;
}

.box :nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <a id="related-posts" href="#">Related Questions</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a id="commentlist" href="#">Answer</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your code in the answer itself using JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet. Shortcut : `Ctrl+M`. You can learn about it here. https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Thabks for the guidance

Comment: Thank you sir for helping me but, in my website where should I paste this code??--in the css stylesheet or additional css?

Comment: Try to paste it on additional css section as shown in the image.

Comment: sir, with help of inspect element, I successfully moved that division down... Is there any way to save those changes from inspect elements to save in that additional CSS?

Comment: You could update these styles on the **Additional CSS**.